# What is required to use TypeScripts Import/Export?

Tags: typescript

So After looking at examples, and trying to cook up something on my own, I'm starting to think that I need an external library to use TypeScript's export/import function, as I get errors saying that `require` and `export` isn't defined.

Anything pointing me in the right direction is most welcome.

```
import * as bar from './bar';
class Foo {
    public Bar(): void {
        console.log(new bar.Bar().message);
    }
}
window.onload = () => {
    new Foo().Bar();
};
```

and

```
export class Bar {
    public message: string = "Hello World!";
}
```

compiles to:

```
"use strict";
var bar = require('./bar');
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.Bar = function () {
        console.log(new bar.Bar().message);
    };
    return Foo;
}());
window.onload = function () {
    new Foo().Bar();
};
//# sourceMappingURL=foo.js.map
```

and

```
"use strict";
var Bar = (function () {
    function Bar() {
        this.message = "Hello World!";
    }
    return Bar;
}());
exports.Bar = Bar;
//# sourceMappingURL=bar.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

> as I get errors saying that require and export isn't defined.

You are most likely using the `nodejs` pattern, i.e. something like

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

You **can** get the definition for `require` from `node.d.ts` (which you should still import e.g. `typings install dt~node --global --save`. But **better** to use `import/require` e.g.:

```
import fs = require('fs');
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm not using nodejs. - Just plain TypeScript compiled through Visual Studio, no framework.

Comment: @Tc_ then your code shouldn't have any `require` statements :)

Comment: the require statements are in the generated JavaScript. TypeScript should not be giving an error. The *runtime* will. Please use a loader like webpack. More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html